# Magento-2.2 development with CSS only (no use of LESS)

Tags: less-css, styles, magento2.2.2

I know Magento 2 uses `LESS` for styling but what if I'd like to build a site with CSS only? 
I don't want to use LESS in my custom theme.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not compulsory to use less css in Magento 2 but as per best practices less is preferable :)

The normal css would also be working fine with Magento 2.

Comment: Yeah, i know but browser reads CSS from styles-l.css and styles-m.css files. So my question is that where can I write my theme's CSS. thankyou

Comment: You can write your css at: app/design/frontend/Magento/{{Your_Theme}}/web/css/source/_theme.less, you can write normal css into this file. Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy once css is added by removing pub/static/frontend, pub/static/_cache folders.